# How can I use Free Dictionary API to get the top definition of a word?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to make a program that spits out the definitions of a word list for a project. I am using https://dictionaryapi.dev/. I've never worked with web apis before, so can I get some help with this.

I've tried
`var data = $.getJSON("https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/hello")`
then
`document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = data.meanings[1].definition`
but it doesn't work. It says it can't find what meanings is.

Comment: `data` is an array. So `data[0]`. But also `meanings` is array of objects and each of those has a `definitions` array. So eventually you're going to end up something like `data[0].meanings[0].definitions[0].definition`. Take time to [look over how the API returns JSON](https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/sand), and what those structures are.

Comment: Well, to start, `data` is NOT the API response as you expect. Just look at the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), you need to pass a callback to `getJSON` and handle the response there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **[flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)** to retrieve just the definitions from the response:

```js
const DICTIONARY_API_BASE_URL =
    'https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/';
const DEFINITIONS_DIV = document.getElementById('definitions');

const fetchWordDefinitions = async word => {
    console.log(`Making request for definitions of ${word}...`);
    const response = await fetch(DICTIONARY_API_BASE_URL + word);
    const json = await response.json();
    return json[0].meanings
        .flatMap(m => m.definitions)
        .flatMap(d => d.definition);
};

const getWordDefinitions = () => {
    const word = document.getElementById('word').value;
    if (word == null || word == '') {
        return alert('Error: You must enter a word to fetch');
    }
    DEFINITIONS_DIV.innerHTML = '';
    fetchWordDefinitions(word)
        .then(defintions => {
            defintions.forEach(d => {
                DEFINITIONS_DIV.innerHTML += `<p>${d}</p>`;
            });
        })
        .catch(_ => {
            DEFINITIONS_DIV.innerHTML += `<p>Error: Could not retrive any defintions for ${word}.</p>`;
        });
};
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Fetch the definitions for a word!</h1>
        <input type="text" id="word" name="word">
        <input type="button" value="Fetch" onClick="getWordDefinitions()">
        <div id="definitions"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do with cases like this is to make use of the `console.log()` function.

```
fetch('https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/english')
.then(response => {
    return response.json();
})
.then(word => {
    console.log(word);
})
```

You can use Chrome developer tools by pressing F12. A console window will open in your browser, here you can expand the [JSON response request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnqAQ.png) returned from `console.log(word);` this will allow you to view each of the child elements. This should give you a better idea of how the structure of the JSON is formatted. Once you understand the [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Euz.png) you can remove the `console.log(word);` and assign it to a variable

```
var singleWordDefinition = word[0].meanings[0].definitions[0].definition;
```

Example Code:

```
function returnDefinition() {
    fetch('https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/hello')
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(word => {
        var singleWordDefinition = word[0].meanings[0].definitions[0].definition;
        console.log("SINGLE: " + singleWordDefinition);

        const wordDefinitionArr = word[0].meanings;
        wordDefinitionArr.forEach(wordDefinition => {
            console.log("FROM ARRAY: " + wordDefinition.definitions[0].definition);
        });
    })
};
```

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FOQG.png)